# Laravel views using with() method

Tags: laravel, laravel-views

I want to pass data to Laravel view and do not understand certain parameters within the `with()` method. What parameter `name` refer to?

```
return view('pages.about')->with('name', $name);
```

Comment: Hi, please amplify your question by explaining what research you have done and why that did not help. Thank you.

Comment: with is used to pass varibale to the respective view file. where you can set like for single variable return view('pages.about')->with('key', value);  

for multiple valriable: return view('pages.about')->with(['key1'=>value,['key2'=>value]);

Comment: You can try ->with(compact("name"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what parameter 'name' refer to

Name is the alias you give to the variable `$name` which you can access in your view.

e.g

```
$name= 'John Doe';
return view('pages.about')->with('myName', $name);
```

So now you can access `$myName` in `about` view

From the docs it says:

> As an alternative to passing a complete array of data to the view
>   helper function, you may use the with method to add individual pieces
>   of data to the view

**Ref: [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views#sharing-data-with-all-views)**

**UPDATE AFTER COMMENTS:** In your case you should use with as below:

```
return view ('pages.absensi')->with('Rfidabs' => $Rfidabs);
```

then in your `abseni` view you can loop through the array as below:

```
foreach ($Rfidabs as $item)
     <tbody> 
        <td>{{$item->id}}</td> 
        <td>{{$item->Name}}</td> 
        <td>{{$item->Kelas}}</td>
     </tbody> 
endforeach
```

Comment: i just guess 'name' is a field of my table in database. are you saying that 'name' is variable in my snippet code?

Comment: @DoniMartGalumbangHutabarat `$name` is a variable which can store anything like as you said your database field entry! And `name` is an alias via which you can access the defined variable in your view.

Comment: i agree with you that 'name' is only alias but i couldn't load my blade view when passing 'name' but succeed when using $name reffer to my snippet. since in your e.g you writte 'myName' as alias and you said i could access it as $myName in view blade

Comment: Can you share your code of how you tried? If you're following my code you can access the name in your about view like this `{{ $myName }}` and it will print `John Doe`

Comment: my controller     public function absensi(){
        $Rfidabs = Rfid::all();
        return view ('pages.absensi' ,['Rfidabs'=>$Rfidabs]);
    }

Comment: my viewblade.        foreach ($Rfidabs as $item) 
                    <tbody>
                            <td>{{$item->id}}</td>
                            <td>{{$item->Name}}</td>
                            <td>{{$item->Kelas}}</td>
                    </tbody>
                  endforeach

Comment: @DoniMartGalumbangHutabarat check the updated answer, i have edited it for your case.

Comment: that is why i confused when you said i could access the alias not the variable. btw i couldn't figure out why alias should be there since found nothing how/ where or when it is used

Comment: @DoniMartGalumbangHutabarat alias is storing your `variable` values so did you tried my updated answer? And what's the error or issue you are facing now?

Comment: as i said i only able to access the data when use $name not the alias ('name') in the view blade

Answer (score 1):

In your controller

```
$user=User::where('id','=',$id)->first();
```

This will load the user with the specific id to the $user object.

If we want to load this object in our view,we will pass the object to the view using 'with' function. It has 2 parameters:the object name and the object which we want to load in the view.

```
return view('user.list')->with('student',$user);
```

In this example i just took a user object and loads in the view as $student.
     In our view we use,

```
  {{$student->name;}}
  {{$student->age;}}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should ha defined `$name` variable.
Then, part `name` (first `with()`'s argument) you are calling as

`{{ $name }}`.

Or from [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views)

> As an alternative to passing a complete array of data to the viewhelper function, you may use the withmethod to add individual pieces of data to the view:

```
return view('greeting')->with('name', 'Victoria');
```

Answer (score 0):

`with` is a variable name you are passing to your view file.

So in your case:

`return view('pages.about')->with('name', $name);`

You are passing a `name` variable name to your `pages.about` blade file.

However, on cases where the variable name you want to pass on the blade file is the same with the variable name you have on your controller, you can just use the `compact` like below:

`return view('pages.about')->with('name', $name);`

is the same as

`return view('pages.about', compact('name'));`

Using `compact` will have an advantage, imagine the situation below:

`return view('pages.about')->with('name', $name)->with('age', $age)->with('gender', $gender)->with('address', $address);`

is the same as

`return view('pages.about', compact('name', 'age', 'gender', 'address'));`

Answer (score 0):

According to your code `name` refer to the variable through you can access data in the view.

```
return view('pages.about')->with('name', $name);
```

You can access data in view like this.

```
<table>
 <tr><th>Name</th></tr>
 <tr><td>{{$name}}</td></tr>
</table>
```